# Audio() как сделать звук потише?

Tags: javascript

Audio() как уменшить громкость звука?

```
function soundClick() {
  var audio = new Audio(); // Создаём новый элемент Audio
  audio.src = 'click.mp3'; // Указываем путь к звуку "клика"
  audio.autoplay = true; // Автоматически запускаем
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
audio.volume = 0.2; // Громкость звука от 0 до 1
```